# Create several .desktop files for the same app Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: dock, favorites

I am trying to put two versions of the same app (Emacs) in my favorites, each launched with different CLI flags. I modified the existing .desktop file and installed it via

```
desktop-file-install --dir=/home/leo/.local/share/applications ./emacs-scratch.desktop
```

however I still see only one instance of the Emacs favorite icon. Is there a way to create a second one? I checked that the new .desktop file is in `~/.local/share/applications` and passes validation.

Comment: Change `Name=` and `GenericName=` in one of the .desktop files... and the title of the .desktop file.